# Illustrator CS6 Actions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, automation, illustrator-scripting, jpg

Is there a way to create an export action in Illustrator where each time the action is run, it asks for a location to export to?
I work on multiple projects where the exported JPEGs need to go into their different respective project folders, having a step in the export action where I could specify the exact location would simplify the process for me.

Comment: If you want it to ask you each time you run the action you can just as well go to `File -> Export` without making any action. If you record it as an action and then enable the dialog you will have the exact same process and no time gain.

Answer (score 1):

Create the action and click on the "Toggle dialog on/off" to the left of the export step.
This way you'll get the export options and will be able to indicate the path.

Comment: But what's the use of creating the action with the dialog? You could just as well hit `File -> Export` to get the same dialog. Is there some difference between using the action and using Export directly?

Comment: you can run a batch on entire folder(s) and although you will have to input your options in the export dialog box everything else will be done automatically via your action